# web.Config Request Filtering, Block files that start with _

Tags: asp-classic, web-config, iis-8

I'm dealing with a legacy classic asp app, and I would like to prevent files that start with underscore "*" from being retrieved via a browser request.  Ideally I want any file that starts with "*" to show a 404 not found exception.

The reason being is I don't want to name my files with the .Inc extension because It makes it a pain in development as I lose syntax highlighting, intellisense, and other things I'm using in Visual Studio.

As this is running in IIS8, is there any way I can filter the request to block these files before the ASP handler processes the page?

Comment: You don't have to use `inc` as an file extension, just retain the .asp standard extension. You can always rename later if you feel you must.

Comment: Yeah, but if it's .asp you can load it in the browser, which is undesired, and I'd rather not rename them.  Just want to set it once and forget it kind of deal.  The below thing I figured out works great, just wish there was a non hack way of doing it.  There are going to be a hundred or so of them, so renaming them and naming them back all the time would be tedious.

Comment: If you're worried about starting the page in the browser then only include functions and/or subs in the file, or include some kind of page start trap.

Answer (score 1):

Temporary Answer:

I mapped ASPClassic in the http handlers twice.  First I mapped it to _*.asp.  However I used an invalid dll for the asp dll, which will cause an error:

The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the ISAPI and CGI Restriction list settings on the Web server.

Which is a 404.2

Then I mapped the normal *.asp handler.

HttpHandlers don't pass to the next HttpHandler if it matches a request.. So the first HttpHandler to match the request is the one that get's used.

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler"/>
      <remove name="ASPClassic"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
      <add name="ASPClassic_No" path="_*.asp" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll2" resourceType="File" />
      <add name="ASPClassic" path="*.asp" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll" resourceType="File" />
    </handlers>
</web.Server>
```

Furthermore, server side includes still work on these files because SSI isn't request dependent.

If anyone knows a cleaner, non hacky way of doing this, I'm all ears!

I was using this asp file to do it prior to this:

```
<%
  notFound_fullName = Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")
  notFound_pathArray = split(notFound_fullName, "/")
  notFound_fname = notFound_pathArray(UBOUND(notFound_pathArray))
  If (InStr(1, notFound_fname, "_") = 1) Then
    Response.Status ="404 Not Found"
    Response.End
  End If
%>
```

However, I ran into a scenario where I needed it to be included on a page that included it on the page, while also including it on the page that was being included.

E.g.

```
_cUser -> include 404handler code (alone with no other includes)
_baseWebService -> Include _AllClasses (includes 404 handler again)
```

Which won't work with option strict, becuase it's either redefining variables, or the variable isn't defined because option strict is on....